# Black Screen Booting Into Linux Mint (On Dual Boot Machine w/SLI + 2 Monitors)

Tags: linux-mint, boot, nvidia, video

I'm currently dual booting Linux Mint and Windows 8 on a machine with dual ASUS nVidia GTX 770s running in SLI (on an ASUS Z97-Deluxe motherboard).  Everything works fine on the Windows side, but when I boot from Windows to Linux the screens both go dark and stay dark as soon as I'm out of GRUB.  If I unplug the second monitor then everything boots up like normal on the first monitor, and then oddly enough if I plug the second monitor back in and then reboot the machine from Linux back into Linux everything works fine and I can use both monitors.  Obviously rebooting the machine twice and having to crawl under the desk and unplug/plugin a cable is less than ideal for my "switch OS" process.  Thanks in advance for any help that you're able to offer!

Comment: When you have the 2 monitors connected, is there something written to /var/log/messages or syslog?

Comment: Try disabling acpi in `/etc/default/grub` change this variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"`, and reboot. Just add `acpi=off` to whatever other directives existed already. I had a similar issue but without two monitors. The power management and a few other features will be controlled by the BIOS firmware after the next reboot. If this "solves" the problem, then the issue is with GNU/Linux software, probably drivers. The fact the Windows works already suggests this. So the problem wont be solved, you need to either use the correct divers, or bugs need fixing, or both.

Comment: Make sure to `sudo update-grub2` after modifying the file and before rebooting, I forgot to say that. I am on a similar boat and have content/lazy since I can boot and shutdown without black screen or random reboots, but I would like to use acpi, so I should probably think about filling a report myself ( I had been blaming my hardware for awhile).

Comment: @ott-- I just rebooted with both monitors and at a glance, it doesn't look like anything under /var/log has been touched.

Comment: @Overloaded_Operator I tried following your suggestion and I got an error when I ran update-grub2, not exactly sure what the issue is.  I haven't touched this stuff for a while, but I remember having to play around with grub-customizer back in the day to get Windows 8 booting correctly.

Comment: The key definitely seems to be booting from Windows versus booting from Linux, but I have no clue why that would impact anything.  What kind of state would be left around?

Comment: @Overloaded_Operator I fixed the issue that was causing the grub update to error out (ended up being quite painful, grub was temporarily unbootable and ended up having to use boot-repair).  Now when I add acpi=off and update I get no video regardless of whether I have one or two monitors plugged in, so I booted into recovery mode and removed that setting.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: @Overloaded_Operator this issue is still killing me, so just to add some context to the message above.  When I add the acpi=off and unplug the second monitor I see that I'm actually getting a kernel panic.  Any ideas?